# Assigning hidden field to a variable

Tags: asp.net

I have an aspx control as follows

```
<input type=""hidden"" value='EmployeeId' id=""employeeID""/>
```

I need some help in making the value of the above hidden field dynamically assigned to a integer variable called EmoployeeId somewhere above this line. Can anyone point out how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: What's up with the odd assortment of double-quotes, single-quotes, and double-double-quotes?

Answer (score 1):

Add `runat="server"` to the markup:

```
<input runat="server" type="hidden" value="" id="employeeID"/>
```

And on code behind, do this:

```
employeeID.Value=valueFromVariable.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you've  ASP.NET then use server control,

```
<asp:HiddenField id="empId" runat="server" value="10"/>
```

and in code behind,

```
int no=int.Parse(empId.Value);

//Or - use int.TryParse
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a server-side variable to a client-side Javascript variable as so (Classic ASP):

```
<script type='test/javascript'>
var myVar = '<% =myServerVar %>' <--- a string
var myNum = <% =myServerVarNUm %> <--- a number
</script>
```